# Bootstrap data-toggle="button" on non-button element

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

simple (and probably easy) my code is as follows

```
<div class="btn-group mod-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Moderálás</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li data-toggle="button" class="publicBtn<?php echo ($s['public'] ? ' active' : '');?>"><a><i class="icon-eye-open"></i> Publikus</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My question is how can I make the li with the `data-toggle="button"` work as a button would with a `data-toggle="button"` so how can I ask bootstrap to remove and add the active class to that li when clicked?

Also the question is **not** how to do this in js as It would be much nicer to accomplish this purely using the bootstrap api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to assign a `role` to the `<li>` element and then the `data-toggle`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/6KffS/108/

```
<ul>
    <li role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="button">Button1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work, can it be because the data-toggle="dropdown"? It's also necessary for the li to have it's own styling defined as a dropdown element

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AfqKz/ open the dropdown menu, only button is active click button, open dropdown menu.
expectations: only button is not active
reality: only button is active

Comment: Add the `btn` class to the element also DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/AfqKz/2/

Comment: hmm... problem is, that messes up the style of the li